# Route.get() requires callback function but got a [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating a REST API with express, folowing the architecture from [this article](https://medium.com/netscape/mean-app-tutorial-with-angular-4-part-1-18691663ea96).
in a nutshell, a router is calling a controller.

here is an example of a call:

```
router.get('/', ModelsController.getModels)
```

This work fine so far, and now, I'm improving error handling with Boom.

I would like to use the wrapper like in [this article](https://michalzalecki.com/an-elegant-solution-for-handling-errors-in-express/), but as I don't use TS and as I am unfamiliar with Promises, I'm struggling with it.

Here is the wrapper:

```
exports.enhanceHandler = async function (handler) {
    return async function (req, res, next) {

        try {
            const result = await handler(req, res);
            if (result instanceof Error && Boom.isBoom(result)) {
                res.status(result.output.statusCode).send(formatBoomPayload(result));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            // now log errors to your errors reporting software
            if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" && (error.stack || error.message)) {
                res.status(500).send(error.stack || error.message);
            } else {
                res.status(500).send(Boom.internal().output.payload);
            }
        }

        next();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call it in my router, like this:

```
router.get('/handler', enhanceHandler(ModelsController.getModels))
```

However, I've got this error:

```
Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Promise]
```

What could I do ? Do I need to resolve the promise ? modify enhanceHandler so it return a function and not a promise ?

Comment: there are conflict using the `async` keyword. If you have `next` parameter you should use all callback

Comment: I add async as await is only valid in async function. Can you tell me more about how to use all callback please?

Comment: Remove `async` keyword from `exports.enhanceHandler = async function (handler)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every promise object have a .then method that you need to use to get the result out of a promise object, like this:

```
handler(req, res).then((res) => {
    if (res instanceof Error && Boom.isBoom(res)) {
        res.status(res.output.statusCode).send(formatBoomPayload(res));
    }
});
```

We can also removes async from the function if we are not using await anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Handler needs to be sync, but the function it returns can remain async.

```
exports.enhanceHandler = function (handler) { // delete "async" keyword
   return async function (req, res, next) {

        try {
            const result = await handler(req, res);
            if (result instanceof Error && Boom.isBoo
    ..
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what's going on. 
You've called get() and for second parameter you've used enhanceHandler() call. 
The call of **any async function returns Promise**. 
While the get  needs a function reference as the second parameter.

So first you have to avoid async keyword on a function which provides the second parameter for get().